# PHP process array question

Tags: php

How can I convert the array below

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => color
            [value] => red
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => color
            [value] => black
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => color
            [value] => green
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => volume
            [value] => 15L
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => volume
            [value] => 25L
        )

)
```

To one like this

```
Array(
    'colors'  => red, black, green
    'volumes' => 15L, 25L
)
```

This code

```
foreach( $result as $r )
    {           
        if( $mem !== $r->name ) unset($attribs[$r->name . "s"]);            
        $string .= $r->value . ", ";                    
        $attribs[$r->name . "s"] = reduce_multiples($string, ", ", TRUE); //removes the last comma from the string          
        $mem = $r->name;                    
    }
```

Prints out

```
Array
(
    [colors] => red, black, green
    [volumes] => red, black, green, 15L, 25L
)
```

$result is the first array snippet above. It's close but not quite there. The line

```
if( $mem !== $r->name ) unset($attribs[$r->name . "s"]);
```

does nothing for the moment but I think it's something along these lines that I need to omit the "red, black, green" from the volumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($oldArray as $obj) {
   $name = $obj->name.'s';
   $value = $obj->value;
   if array_key_exists($name,$newArray) {
      $newArray[$name] .= ', '.$value;
   } else {
      $newArray[$name] = $value;
   }
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function which iterates through the array, generating the type of array you want. There is no builtin method.